# iPad as a keyboard for Mac using Bluetooth

Tags: ios, macos, ipad, bluetooth, keyboard

I want to use my iPad as a keyboard for my Mac-Mini/MacBook using Bluetooth. So please suggest me how can I do this.

Please provide me the any link that help me regarding this.

Thanks

Comment: You would need to write an app for the iPad and a companion app for OS X. The app on iOS would send data to the OS X app and this would then need to provide the keyboard input simulation on OS X. An iOS device cannot act as a Bluetooth keyboard directly.

Answer (score 2):

One option is that you take your iPad as an peripheral and Mac-Mini/MacBook as central, and implement HOGP(Hid Over Gatt Profile).
Their are several things need to be done on your iPad:
1)An app which collect the keyboard event, i.e. a virtual input keyboard(just like the original input keyboard on iPad) needed to collect keyboard event.
2)A descriptor which describe your virtual keyboard event is needed, used for your MAC to parse your keyboard event. for this case you may need refer HOGP which defined on Bluetooth SIG website. 
https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=245141
3)Normal Bluetooth actions, such as advertisement/connection handler.

basically you need to nothing on you MAC but purely app development on your iPad. for the section 2, if you can sniff the Bluetooth air trace, you may find a real Bluetooth keyboard and find out the descriptor, then copy/reuse it.

Due to the iOS version issue, some of the old device may not support Bluetooth advertisement function hence your app could no run on such iOS version.